# Why am I facing with empty graph without any error?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

plt.plot(norway.Freedom, norway.Economy_GDP_per_Capita, color = 'navy', label = 'Norway')

plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.title('Effect of GDP against Freedom')
plt.xlabel('Freedom')
plt.ylabel('GDP')

plt.show()
```

Example row in the data:
[image: Data Frame]

Output:
[image: Graph]

I make a quick start to Data Science and I am trying to make some analysis on Kaggle. I write a kernel for plotting a line as you see in my code, although the graph is empty and I can not see anything.
Besides that, there is no error or something. I need help with it.
Please try to explain without going deep, I am a beginner.
Thanks everybody who will help.

I am not sure whether you guys can see my code and graph...

Comment: Please don't add code as images. [Edit] your question to fix it up. Also reduce your problem to a single plot. See also [mcve].

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code, but the code itself. Also in your case, please include two or five example points in the code, we don't need the whole data.

Comment: What can I do instad of?

Comment: Paste your code directly

Comment: Getting better. Now leave only one plot. If the problem persists, plot dummy data, like `plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])`. See where it goes wrong. The [mcve] is a key step in debugging.

Comment: Now use only a single line like `plt.plot(...)` and use example points also embedded in the code.

Comment: I tried using only a single line. The result is still the same, it is empty. But, plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6]) is working.

Comment: So [edit] your question with all information.

Comment: Also google along the lines of "matplotlib empty plot". Your OS and program/library versions and matplotlib backend will likely all be relevant.

Comment: I think the problem is because of my data frame, I edited it can you check it, please?
Because when I put random numbers in x-axis and y-axis it is showing a line.

Comment: You should try coming up with a runnable example input. I don't see how a row of a dataframe will turn into `norway.Freedom` etc. You are using pandas, right?

Comment: What is `len(norway)`? The question would be easier to answer, if you provide the `DataFrame` itself; see e.g. [this guide to making efficient `pandas` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/5085211)

Comment: Using pandas, yes. len(norway) is 1.

Comment: Guys I am also new on stackoverflow so I dont know how to use, how to edit all informations about my promlem. Sorry for that. But thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because your dataframe has only one single row, therefore both norway.Freedom and norway.Economy_GDP_per_Capita are just single numbers so you are trying to plot one single point.  If you try to plot this without markers, you'll see nothing. Try

```
plt.plot(norway.Freedom, norway.Economy_GDP_per_Capita, 'x', color = 'navy', label = 'Norway')
```

which adds x-markers to the plot.

Or choose a dataframe with more than one row of data...

Comment: Nice catch. I thought that was only a row.

Comment: Probably the right answer, but they say that the row is an "example row", which could suggest that there's more than one.

Comment: I'm not sure; the word 'example' was added later in an edit. However, the coordinates of the point in this row do not fit to the scales in the graph... Anyway, if you see nothing, adding markers is never a too bad idea... :)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that too late. You right data frame has only one row. But I did not know that I can mark a point. Thanks.